# Properly update pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update missing values in a column in a `pandas` dataframe, but am getting a warning about the method.  When I change to the suggestion, I still get the same error.  What can I do to not get yelled at by pandas?

First attempt:

```
df['column1'].fillna(inplace=True, value='Low')
```

First response:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:3295: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Second attempt:

```
df.loc[df['column1'].isnull(), 'column1'] = 'Low'
```

Second response:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:476: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.replace()`? Basically: `import numpy as np; df.replace({'column1: {np.nan: 'Low'}'}, inplace = True)`?

Comment: How did you get `df`?  You may be getting the warning because `df` itself was created by slicing some other DataFrame.

Comment: @BrenBarn = I build df from a subset of big_df.  `df = big_df[big_df['columnA'] == 'X']`

Comment: @mikebmassey: That is probably why you're getting the warning.  If you don't care whether `big_df` is affected, you can likely ignore the warning.  You could also make a copy (`df = big_df[big_df['columnA'] == 'X'].copy()`) so that pandas will know `df` is no longer "linked" to `big_df`.

Comment: @Abdou Not liking .replace() either.  `df.replace({'column1': {np.nan: 'Low'}}, inplace = True)
                                   ^
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: @BrenBarn Yup.  That did it.  I have never had a need to .copy(), but will start.  Thanks.  Post this as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I think @BrenBarn is right. `df` must be referencing the bigger dataframe still.

Comment: @BrenBarn I was looking everywhere to solve this mystery. I'm glad I came across your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like `df` itself is creating by slicing a larger `big_df`.  This is the reason for the warning.  Anytime you get a slice of a DataFrame and try to modify it, you have the possibility of getting this warning, since there is uncertainty about whether modifying `df` will also affect the `big_df` of which it is a part.

If you don't care about the effect on `big_df` you can likely ignore the warning.  The other solution is to use `.copy()` when creating `df` to ensure that you get an "unencumbered" DataFrame that is not linked to the original larger one.